# Regex accepting forward slashes and ` in C# although I am not allowing any

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0, regex-group

What I want to do is that the name should only consist of `.`, `-`, `_`, and alphanumeric characters in any order. So in order to implement this, I am using the following RegEx.

```
@"^[a-zA-z0-9_.-]+$"
```

But the above RegEx is accepting Backslash characters and ` (Backtick) sign also.

Comment: Fix as `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$"`

Comment: This doesnt works for me it is still accepting forward slashes

Comment: No, [it doesn't](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5ba-zA-Z0-9_.-%5d%2b%24&i=%2f%2f%2f%2f%2f).

Comment: yeah my bad i was using A-z instead of A-Z thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Add this in Key press event :: e.Handled = !(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back || char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar));

Comment: @JJ's that is not a method of validation yeah that is an kind of alternative but not the right way to do it I got it working for me thanks I was using a 'z' instead of Z